# Numpy: Get the smallest value within indices without loop?

Tags: python, numpy

Lets assume I have the follwing arrays:

```
distance = np.array([2, 3, 5, 4, 8, 2, 3])
idx = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2 ])
```

Now I want the smallest distance within one index. So my goald would be:

```
result = [2, 4, 2]
```

My only idea right now would be something like this:

```
for i in idx_unique:
    result.append(np.amin(distances[np.argwhere(idx = i)]))
```

But is there a faster way without a loop??

Answer (score 1):

You can convert `idx` to a boolean vector to use indexing within the distance vector:

```
distance = np.array([2, 3, 5, 4, 8])
idx = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1]).astype(np.bool)

result = [np.min(distance[~idx]), np.min(distance[idx])]
```

Comment: oh in my example I have only two idx, but that bool option would not work for more than 2 right?

Comment: Exactly, you could always rewrite your loop in a longer expression, but for too many indexes this method is not helpful

Answer (score 1):

Although not truly free from loops, here is one way to do that:

```
import numpy as np

distance = np.array([2, 3, 5, 4, 8, 2, 3])
idx = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2 ])

t = np.split(distance, np.where(idx[:-1] != idx[1:])[0] + 1)
print([np.min(x) for x in t])
```

Actually, this provides no improvement as both the OP's solution and this one has the same runtime:

```py
res1 = []
def soln1():
    for i in idx_unique:
        res1.append(np.amin(distances[np.argwhere(idx = i)]))

def soln2():
    t = np.split(distance, np.where(idx[:-1] != idx[1:])[0] + 1)
    res2 = [np.min(x) for x in t]
```

Timeit gives:

```py
%timeit soln1
#10000000 loops, best of 5: 24.3 ns per loop
```

```py
%timeit soln2
#10000000 loops, best of 5: 24.3 ns per loop
```